# What to do with an old windows 2008 r2 server with old windows updates

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an old windows 2008 R2 (SP1) server that hasn't had a windows update installed in a long time. We've ran out of space (less than 4 GB) and would like to clean up old windows updates to free up space.

Has anyone had any experience with installing windows updates on a server that is far behind? How long should it take? How much downtime should I expect? Should I just wipe the slate clean and re-download updates? Should I manually install updates to get caught up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately, Microsoft stopped releasing updates the way they did back then, so a system doesn't need to install 300+ updates.

For the base operating system, all you need is the most recent servicing stack update, and the Security Monthly Quality Rollup. There may be some .NET Framework 4 updates as well.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4490628/servicing-stack-update-for-windows-7-sp1-and-windows-server-2008-r2

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4503292/windows-7-update-kb4503292

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4499406/security-and-quality-rollup-for-net-framework

If you don't have the disk cleanup update installed, you can copy cleanmgr.exe and cleanmgr.exe.mui from another system that does, and run that to remove the older updates from the WinSxS folder. The removal of old updates requires a restart to go into effect.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2014/05/13/how-to-clean-up-the-winsxs-directory-and-free-up-disk-space-on-windows-server-2008-r2-with-new-update/